# Tracking two objects at the same time in ARImageTrackingConfiguration

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, swift5

I want to link two 3D models to two different trackers. I snap the tracker to the reference photo, but I don’t understand how tracking two objects at the same time in `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`

```
guard let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos2", bundle: Bundle.main) else {
    print("No images available")
    return
}
```

I snap the tracker to the reference photo, but I don’t understand how tracking two objects at the same time in `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it into ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func trackingConfig() {

        guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", 
                                                                           bundle: nil)
        else {
            return
        }

        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.detectionImages = referenceImages
        let options: ARSession.RunOptions = [.resetTracking,                                        
                                             .removeExistingAnchors] 
        sceneView.session.run(config, options: options)
    }
}
```

Then create an extension containing renderer method an a switch inside function:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
                 didAdd node: SCNNode,
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
              let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
        else {
            return
        }

        let geometryNode = nodeGetter(name: imageName)
        node.addChildNode(geometryNode)
    }

    func nodeGetter(name: String) -> SCNNode {

        var node = SCNNode()

        switch name {
            case "geometry_01": node = geoOne
            case "geometry_02": node = geoTwo
            default: break
        }
        return node
    }
}
```

Comment: In the switch, what values should "geometry_01" and geo01 take?

Comment: case "geometry_01" brings `geoOne` node containing some geometry. Or what's your question about?